# How can I show an external WordPress site under a asp.net site domain

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, iis

I have a asp.net site www.example.com on a Microsoft server. I also have a WordPress site on a Linux server. I need my WordPress site to be visible under a folder on my asp.net site.

E.g. www.example.com is my asp.net site but I would like www.example.com/mysite to show the WordPress site.

I know you can host WordPress on Microsoft servers but that is not an option for me.

Comment: Can you use HTML iframe element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. You can have subdomain though blog.example.com and point it to your linux server.

Comment: This is my 'plan b' if no one can help me out

Comment: i think it's better anyway to have subdomain. Since you need to maintain 2 servers, you have 2 ip, thus 2 subdomains. It's more clear cut in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use IIS 7.0 URL Rewrite to create a [reverse proxy](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/805/reverse-proxy---rule-template/) to you blog. I know this sounds a little intimidating, but essentially you can get IIS to serve up your wordpress blog as a sub-folder just like you want.